# how to upload .zip on diawi

Tags: ios, ipa, .app, diawi

I am trying to upload .ipa but got the error:-

> The application package is not a valid package : no payload folder found in the package.
> A technical error occuredsome technical error occurred.

I put the right development provisioning profile and respective certificate.

Provide me the steps to create and upload .zip on [diawi](http://www.diawi.com/) ?

Comment: ipa only we can upload in diwai . I think you try to upload the application package in diawi

Comment: Try .ipa upload . You might be uploading a project zip file not an ipa.zip

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik:- I build the product for generic devices. Process it to iTunes. Then get the ipa(by show in finder). I am uploading that ipa to diawi.

Comment: @MuhammadAdnan: I am uploading .ipa. (Steps that I followed written above)

Comment: @PKC456 you can create ipa with development profile and share via diawi

Answer (score 7):

Try this
**Select build generic device** -> **Clean project** - > **Build project** -> **Select Project** scroll down and **Select Product** and select your.app file.Right click on that and choose **show in finder** and make compress that .app file and upload .zip into Diawi.
Hope this Helps

Answer (score 1):

You can only upload a .ipa file to diawi for distribution.

You can find the steps to create an IPA file from the link below

[Steps to create and export IPA](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW1)

Also try building with AdHoc provisional profile. If the issue persists then try refreshing the page and do the upload again.

In my past experience diawi has shown some browser specific issues also. So try using different browsers also.

Hope it helps....

Comment: Can I use development certificates to create ipa and upload on diawi?

Comment: @pkc456 yes you can.... But sometimes the issues that we get are really crazy. So i just told you an alternative.